# Gradle - Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:[2.7.10,)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, version-control, spring-boot-starter

I am trying to use gradle's Version Range Matchers as so:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:[2.7.10,)'
```

But for some reason getting this error:

> Could not resolve
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:[2.7.10,).

When trying to get the specific version, as:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.10'
```

it seems to work fine.
My full `build.gradle` of the module:

```
plugins {
    id 'my-company-spring-lib'
}

dependencies {
        // Web
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:[2.7.10,)'
    
        implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    
        // Linter
        implementation "com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:8.27"
        // Logging
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
        // Logger
        implementation "my.company.package:logger-utils:3.0.0"
        // For WebClient
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
    
        //For hmac verification
        implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
}
```

And this is the project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryJavaLocalUrl}"
            credentials{
                username = System.getenv("JFROG_USER")
                password = System.getenv("JFROG_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "my.company.package:gradle-common-plugins:${gradleCommonPluginsVersion}"
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

gradle version - 7.5.1

Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me with `[2.7.10,)` resolving to `3.0.5` at the time of writing. Can you share a minimal `build.gradle` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, I've added the build files.

Comment: I can't see why that wouldn't work, but it's hard to be sure as your company-specific plugins are an unknown. Can you reduce things down to create a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve)?